# Dereferencing multiple pointers repeatedly, less efficient?

Tags: c

Instead of writing:

```
string name = first->next->next->next->name;
int age = first->next->next->next->age;
```

Writing it as:

```
node* billy_block = first->next->next->next;

string name = billy_block->name;
int age = billy_block->age;
```

is more efficient? Is it possible the variable `billy_block` will be "optimized away" by the compiler?

I don't understand compilers, so please use simple terms.

Comment: What do you mean by "`billy_block` optimised away"?

Comment: A good optimizer will probably assign a register for `billy_block` if thats what you ask

Comment: @CoffeeandCode, I dont understand compilers. Is it possible 'billy_block' wont exist in the final code at all - on the stack?

Comment: @samofoz your first and second examples would probably be optimized into the same object code if that's all you'll do with `billy_block`

Answer (score 3):

Any self-respecting modern compiler will optimize the original code to eliminate the repetitive dereferencing of the same chain of pointers in situations when it is safe.

But, firstly, the original version of the code is much less readable than the one that uses an intermediate variable. When pointer dereference chains are long, it is not immediately obvious to a human eye that the chains are identical. The variant with the intermediate variable makes it explicitly clear that we want to read `name` and `age` from the same object. In the first variant it is not even remotely as clear.

Secondly, in situations when the aliasing picture is not as obvious to the compiler as in your case, the compiler might have to abandon optimizations. E.g. in general case when you do something like

```
some_ptr->next = first->next->next->next->next;
some_ptr->prev = first->next->next->next->prev;
```

the compiler cannot be sure that the first assignment does not affect the value of `first->next->next->next`. (Consider what happens if `some_ptr` is equal to `first`.) This forces the compiler to play it safe and reevaluate `first->next->next->next` every time from the very beginning. In this case introducing an intermediate variable will indeed optimize the code. For that, of course, you yourself have to be sure that this is the right thing to do, i.e. to use your own knowledge of possible aliasings in your program.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler can only coalesce two loads:

```
int x = *p;
...;
int y = *p;
```

if all of:

- `p` is not a pointer to volatile.
- there are no writes during the `...` that may alias.

The problem of alias analysis is *really hard*, so this mostly means *any* write. On the other hand, the problem of creating additional variables that are only assigned once and then read zero or more times is fundamentally how compilers work, so never hesitate to add a temporary.

---

If anyone comes across this answer and is using C++, however, beware of destructor ordering.

Answer (score 2):

What optimizations a compiler does depends on which compiler you use and the optimization flags you pass to it. You can always examine the assembler code the compiler outputs to see what it has done.

For example, the compiler that came installed with Xcode (Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)), with the appropriate definitions for `node`, does not remove the duplicate access chain even with the highest optimization settings:

```
    movq    %rdi, %rbx
    movq    (%rbx), %rax
    movq    (%rax), %rax
    movq    (%rax), %rsi
    addq    $8, %rsi
    leaq    -40(%rbp), %r14
    movq    %r14, %rdi
    callq   __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEC1ERKS5_
    movq    (%rbx), %rax
    movq    (%rax), %rax
    movq    (%rax), %rax
    movl    32(%rax), %ebx
```

If you use a temporary variable though the compiler just reuses the register `%rbx`, so you get the temporary for free:

```
    movq    (%rdi), %rax
    movq    (%rax), %rax
    movq    (%rax), %rbx
    leaq    8(%rbx), %rsi
    leaq    -40(%rbp), %r14
    movq    %r14, %rdi
    callq   __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEC1ERKS5_
    movl    32(%rbx), %ebx
```

Here's the test program:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string myname;

struct node {
    node *next;
    string name;
    int age;
};

int foo1(node *first) {
    string name = first->next->next->next->name;
    int age = first->next->next->next->age;
    myname=name;
    return age;
}


int foo2(node *first) {
    node* billy_block = first->next->next->next;
    string name = billy_block->name;
    int age = billy_block->age;
    myname=name;
    return age;
}
```

Compiler options `g++ -Wall -S -O3 test.cpp`