# Is it a good practice to repeatedly use struct in C?

Tags: c, performance, struct

Suppose I have these two structs coming from different header files:

> header_1.h

```
struct main_node {
    struct *sec_node
}
```

> header_2.h

```
struct sec_node {
    int var;
}
```

Now I am using this both header files in `main.c` and the code looks something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header_1.h"
#include "header_2.h"

struct main_node *node;

void main()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
      printf( "%d\n", node->sec_node->var) ;
}
```

Let's assume, I am not using a modern optimizing compiler. I'm looping over this `struct` many times, would it be faster/good practice to use a temp variable here?

Is there any difference performance-wise in C?

```
void main()
{
   int temp = node->sec_node->var;
   for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
      printf( "%d\n", temp);
}
```

Comment: the compiler will optimize it itself.

Comment: Do you have anything from a profiler that indicates your current code is a bottleneck? If not, then don't worry about it. Premature optimization is a waste of time.

Comment: Let's assume, I am not using a modern optimizing compiler.

Comment: @Sedmaister Then your effort is probably best spent adding a modern optimizing compiler into your toolchain rather than doing these kinds of optimizations yourself. If you want to know if it's faster though, why not just run your code and measure?

Comment: If your compiler doesn't optimize this, it _is_  faster with the temp variable. But in your case the overhead of `printf` will be much bigger anyway, so it wouldn't make any noticable difference.

Comment: The issue of the `struct` being in two other files certainly makes no difference to the  question concerning run-time performance..

Comment: Who voted to close this? It's actually a fairly deep C question. The word "bad" may have been poorly chosen but it can be clarified in a way that's well-posed.

Comment: @P__J__ Actually, most compilers will not optimize a case such as this, most compilers will assume the global `node` variable can be changed when calling functions in another translation unit, and will have to re-load the pointer for each iteration - which it does not need to do when saving the value in a temp variable right before the loop starts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dereferencing multiple pointers repeatedly, less efficient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31261251/dereferencing-multiple-pointers-repeatedly-less-efficient)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not *bad*, but it can be a source of optimization bottleneck. Because the compiler cannot see the definitions of external functions (like `printf` here, although it might know about its properties as a builtin because it's a standard function), it must assume any external function could modify any non-`const` object whose address it could see. As such, in your example, `node` or `node->sec_node` may have a different value before and after the call to the external function.

One way to mitigate this is with temps like you're doing, but you can also make use of the `restrict` keyword as a promise to the compiler that, during the lifetime of the `restrict`-qualified pointer, the pointed-to object will not be accessed except via pointers "based on" the `restrict`-qualified one. How to do this is probably outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Is what you wrote true only because the OP was using global variables are their instances where local variable can suffer the same problem?

Comment: @doron: Yes. The common case is that the pointer to the structure was an argument to your function, your function is external, and was potentially called from another translation unit. In that case the compiler has no way to know if other external functions can see the pointed-to object and must assume they can.